# How do I simplify my code by making one addAndSubtract function?

Tags: javascript, html

Like the title says, I would like to simplify this JavaScript so that I have one `addAndSubtract` function for the buttons.

I am quite new and I have no idea how to go about it.

Here is the code:

```js
let add= document.querySelector("#add");
let subtract = document.querySelector("#subtract");

add.addEventListener("click",function(){
let output = document.querySelector("#output");
let result = Number(output.innerText) + 1;
if (result >10){
    result = 10;
}

output.innerText = result;
});


subtract.addEventListener("click",function(){
let output = document.querySelector("#output")
let result = Number(output.innerText) - 1;

if (result<0){
    result=0;
}

output.innerText = result;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Le Count!</h1>
    <div class = "Counter_Container">
        <button id="subtract">-</button><span id="output">0</span><button id="add">+</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the desired result? By clicking of the first button, it adds and on the second it subtracts? What is the reason of wanting to aggregate the functions into one? I could see a function that given a parameter or a data tag on the button branches into two cases, but that is more cumbersome than having two separate functions.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea, you should separate concerns

Answer (score 0):

You can read the ID of the button being clicked in the handler, and act accordingly. (The `switch` could be a series of `if`s too.)

```js
function handleClick(event) {
  const action = event.target.id;
  const output = document.querySelector("#output");
  let value = parseInt(output.innerText);
  switch (action) {
    case "add":
      value++;
      break;
    case "subtract":
      value--;
      break;
  }
  value = Math.min(10, Math.max(value, 0)); // clamp to 0..10
  output.innerText = value;
}

document.querySelector("#subtract").addEventListener("click", handleClick);
document.querySelector("#add").addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

```html
<h1>Le Count!</h1>
<div class="Counter_Container">
  <button id="subtract">-</button><span id="output">0</span><button id="add">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function as following

```
function operation(val,maxvalue,minvalue){
let output = document.querySelector("#output")
let result = Number(output.innerText) + val;

if (result<minvalue){
    result=minvalue;
}
if (result>maxvalue){
    result=maxvalue;
}

output.innerText = result;
```

}

And use as below

```
let subtract = document.querySelector("#subtract");

subtract.addEventListener("click",operation.bind(this,-1,10,0))

let add = document.querySelector("#add");

add.addEventListener("click",operation.bind(this,1,10,0))
```

Let me know if you face any issue

Comment: Unlike OP's code, this allows you to go past `10`.

Comment: added max and min value condition

Answer (score 0):

Create a single function which takes your result number and add/subtract as parameter.

```js
    function eventer(result_param, arithmat){
            let output = document.querySelector("#output")
            if(arithmat){
             let result = Number(output.innerText) + 1;
            }else{
             let result = Number(output.innerText) - 1;
}
            if (result<result_param){
                result=0;
            }
        }
```

Always try to make your similar code converted to reusable functions and if_else to ternary operators.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a data attribute to each button that describes the operation that should be performed. Use the same click handler and check the attribute for which operation should be performed.

It's also easier to keep track of the value in a scoped variable too.

```js
let value = 0;
const output = document.querySelector("#output");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".operation");

const operations = {
  add: () => value = Math.min(++value, 10),
  subtract: () => value = Math.max(--value, 0)
};

const setOutput = () => {
  output.innerText = value;
};

// set initial output value
setOutput();

[...buttons].forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const operation = e.target.dataset.operation;

    let func = operations[operation];
    func && func();

    setOutput();
  });
});
```

```html
<h1>Le Count!</h1>
<div class="Counter_Container">
  <button id="subtract" class="operation" data-operation="subtract">-</button>
  <span id="output"></span>
  <button id="add" class="operation" data-operation="add">+</button>
  <button id="multiply" class="operation" data-operation="multiply">*</button>
</div>
```